# Timestamp message ros2 - python

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I`m trying to form the timestamp message in ROS2 (dashing) in **python**.

When I use

```
msg.header.stamp = node.get_clock().now()
```

I have the error:

> The 'stamp' field must be a sub message of type 'Time'

Thanks in advance! :)

'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354203/timestamp-message-ros2---python/) by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2020-06-05

Post score: 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `to_msg()` to convert from `rclpy.time.Time` to `builtin_interfaces.msg.Time`

```
  msg.header.stamp = node.get_clock().now().to_msg()
```

[Link to `Time.to_msg()` in rclpy/time.py](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/196669e539dd51bc56f9f4fdf6f0222d99480d0d/rclpy/rclpy/time.py#L138-L140)

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on 2020-06-07**:
Tks!! It totally works! :D